# How to add buttons and label in table cell dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am developing an iphone application in that i have a requirement as showned in below template [image]

Comment: Any update on your Question regarding our answers..?

Answer (score 0):

you can add create `UIButton` and add them to cell as `subView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method.
You can subClass `UITableViewCell` and in init method create a UIButton and add to subView. 
You can also create cell via xib and load them dynamically.
 A tutorial to customize `UITableViewCell` http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

Answer (score 0):

This is totally depend upon your coding. You need to write the logic for the tableview cell in the method like :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UILabel *lblTeam = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:321];
        UILabel *lblCRank = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:258];
        UILabel *lblPRank = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:369];

*// You can set the CGRectMake co-ordinates using variable like CGRectMake((x+12), (y+3), 120, 15); below  *

        if(!lblTeam){
            lblTeam = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 52, 120, 15)];
            lblTeam.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblTeam.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:103/255.0 green:103/255.0 blue:103/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            lblTeam.tag = 321;
            lblTeam.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:12.0];
            [cell addSubview:lblTeam];
            [lblTeam release];

            lblCRank = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 19, 150, 25)];
            lblCRank.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblCRank.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:168/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            lblCRank.tag = 258;
            lblCRank.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:14.0];
            [cell addSubview:lblCRank];
            [lblCRank release];

            lblPRank = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(187, 20, 40, 25)];
            lblPRank.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblPRank.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:168/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            lblPRank.tag = 369;
            lblPRank.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:12.0];
            [cell addSubview:lblPRank];
            [lblPRank release];

        }
        //Set the values of the labels or buttons here-
        [lblPRank setText:@""];
        [lblCRank setText:@""];
        lblTeam.text = [countryName uppercaseString];
        return  cell;
   }
```

If you still face any problem, show us your code which you are trying we can help you much better then.